# SQLAlchemy custom field with default value for file uploads in Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm trying to create a custom field in SQLAlchemy for managing uploaded files in a Flask application. I'm basically trying to achieve something similar to Django's FileField.

So what I want to be able to do is, given a model:

```
class TestModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "testmodel"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    profile_photo = Column(FileField(upload_set, 100))
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
m = TestModel()
m.profile_photo.save(request.files["profile_photo"])
models.db.session.add(m)
models.db.session.commit()
```

What I have is based on the built in String type and works like this:

```
class FileField(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = String

    def __init__(self, upload_set, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.upload_set = upload_set

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return value.filename
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return FileNameString(self.upload_set, value)


class FileNameString(object):

    def __init__(self, upload_set, filename):
        self.upload_set = upload_set
        self.filename = filename

    def save(self, req_file):
        self.filename = self.upload_set.save(req_file)
        return self.filename

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self.upload_set.url(self.filename)
```

This works when the model exists in the database but not when the model is created from scratch as the `profile_photo` attribute is `None`. Ideally I want the default value of this type to be a blank `FileField`, although I haven't figured out exactly what that would look like. The problem is that I can't figure out how to create a default value for the attribute without having to do something in the constructor of any class which uses the `FileField`.

So, any idea how to create a default value for the `profile_photo` attribute?

Comment: Did you try profile_photo = Column(FileField(upload_set, 100), default=None)?

Comment: Also I might suggest that you not store images in your database, but rather upload to a folder on your server or AWS and store the image path instead. That being said, here is a library which seems to accomplish what you are trying to do. https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.org/en/0.8.0/guide/declare.html

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to store the actual file in the database, I'm storing the filename and using the Flask-uploads package to manage the storage of the file on the file system. What I'm trying to do here is create a field which encapsulates that. sqlalchemy-imageattach looks interesting, I don't like the idea of creating a new table just for managing a simple string, although it is nicer from a relational point of view I suppose as one doesn't end up with NULL values in the field column.

Comment: The `default=None` approach doesn't work as the `FileField.process_result_value` is not called when creating the object.

Comment: i am currently fighting to understand: why the FileField.process_result_value is not called when creating the object