# How to set default value to a custom type in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to set a column default value for my custom column type.

Currently I have this:

```
score = Column(ScoreType, default=Score())
```

or

```
score = Column(ScoreType, ColumnDefault(Score()))
```

I create a database entry without setting the score explicitly with `score=Score()`. When I try to access the `score` instance (`entry.score.total += 1`), I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total'`.
If I create a database entry with explicit setting of the score, then it works.

For example the following with `DateTime` type works:

```
timestamp = Column(DateTime, ColumnDefault(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

My type class looks like this:

```
class ScoreType(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return repr(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return Score.create_score(value)
```

I use another class for this:

```
class Score:
    def __init__(self, result: int = 0, total: int = 0):
        self.total = total
        self.result = result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.result}/{self.total}"

    @classmethod
    def create_score(cls, string: str) -> 'Score':
        r, t = int(string.split('/'))
        return cls(result=int(r), total=int(t))
```

Any idea how to set the default value?

[Another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821002/sqlalchemy-custom-field-with-default-value-for-file-uploads-in-flask) dealt with a similar topic. However, it does not exactly fit my problem and has not yet been answered conclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adjusting the init method:

```
if not kwargs.get('score'):
    self.score = Score()
```